# Using String.substring for Words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following example where I am putting a limit on the characters entered in the Textarea:

```
var tlength = $(this).val().length;
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxchars));
    var tlength = $(this).val().length;
    remain = maxchars - parseInt(tlength);
    $('#remain').text(remain);
```

where maxchars is the number of characters. How can I change this example to work with words, so instead of restricting chars, I restrict to a number of words.

http://jsfiddle.net/PzESw/106/

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/PzESw/110/

Comment: @adeneo My previous example took care of paste scenarios for chars. I want them for words too. So basically the same example working as-is for words

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change one string of your code to something like this:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().split(' ').slice(0, maxchars).join(' '));
```

This code splits text in an array of words (you may need another workflow), removes extra words and joins them back

Comment: What about new lines ?

Comment: you can use regexps instead of ' ' string
i thing something like this is what you need: /[ \n]/

Comment: If you see the demo created by RajaPrabhu, when the last word is typed and a space is put after it, the code removes the space and appends the new word to the last word. So it becomes a never ending chunk of text as the text keeps appending to the last word

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to converting the full String into array of words.

For example you're having a String as:

```
var words = "Hi, My name is Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan.";
var arrayOfWords = words.split(" "); // split at a white space
```

Now, you'll have an array of words. Loop it using

```
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  /* write them all, or limit them in the for loop! */
}
```

This way, you can write the number of words in the document. Instead of characters!